# nvm and node --version disagree?

Tags: node.js, nvm

Can anyone explain how when I do `node --version` I get a version of Node which doesn't appear in the output of `nvm -ls` ?

```
glaucon@polo /media/poloextra/dev/souvenir $ node --version
v7.10.0
glaucon@polo /media/poloextra/dev/souvenir $ nvm ls
         v4.2.2
         v5.5.0
         v7.7.2
         v8.0.0
->       system
default -> stable (-> v8.0.0)
node -> stable (-> v8.0.0) (default)
stable -> 8.0 (-> v8.0.0) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
```

It's a little while since I've used Node and I think perhaps I've misunderstood how nvm does what it does. I thought if there was a version of Node installed then it would appear in the `nvm ls` output

---

**EDIT1** : Responding to comment the output of `which -a node` is :

```
glaucon@polo /media/poloextra/dev/souvenir $ which -a node
/usr/local/heroku/bin/node
/home/glaucon/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/bin/node
/usr/local/bin/node
/usr/bin/node
```

Comment: What happens with `which -a node`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills - thanks for your response. I will update the question to include the output

Comment: The node you're using appears to be the heroku toolbelt node binary or something like that. `nvm` doesn't know about it. Not quite sure why it's the default -- it probably has to do with how you've set your `$PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

(nvm maintainer here) This is intentional; `nvm ls` (and `nvm current`) outputs that you're using the "system" node; which happens to be `v7.10.0`. If you run `nvm use node`, you'll use the latest nvm-installed version, which seems to be v8.0.0 (based on your `nvm ls` output).

You can also run `nvm alias default node` which will auto-use the latest version every time `nvm.sh` is sourced (ie, when you open your terminal).